# Hooking disk write and getting the data being written

Tags: winapi

Is there a way to hook disk writes by a specific application and get the data being written, aside from reading the data after the write or reading process memory and searching for data? It's important for me to get the data before it can be tampered with on the disk. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The supported way of doing this is with a file system filter driver.

Comment: Which is another way of saying it is unsupported, a filter driver can't filter for a specific process.  Injecting a DLL and hooking CreateFile + WriteFile with, say, Detours is something you only do when you are *really* desperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too little reputation to comment, sorry.

I would have said (to echo Raymond) mini filters would fit your requirements nicely.

[Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

FltGetRequestorProcessId should allow you to filter by process.

You will still see every request come through, just match the pid you are interested in. If it is not your process return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK and you will not worry about that request again.

Comment: Thanks, a really thorough response!